# Ruby on Rails fundraising progress bar

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, progress-bar

what is the standard way to create a Ruby on Rails slider progress bar for a crowdfunding website?

I am creating one and need a way to be able to show how much a specific campaign has fundraised and how much is left to reach campaign objective.

I have not been able to find anything that is specific Rails just only a few Jquery plugin. Is there anything simpler that can be done without having to resort to Javascript/JQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using pure CSS. Let's assume that campaign goal is $30000. Users have already donated $12500. So, our progress bar should be (12500 / 30000 * 100%) approximately 42%.

project.rb (e.g.)

```
def progress
  pledged / goal * 100
end
```

style.css

```
.progress-bar-wrapper {
  background-color: #CCC;
  height: 20px;
  width 100%;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #33CC33;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Lets use erb

```
<div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: #{@project.progress}%"></div>
</div>
```

So, we return 42,777 from progress method, add % sign to it and put in style of progress-bar as width. progress-bar div is located inside progress-bar-wrapper div so it will be 42% of it's width.